# Relative homology of a torus relative to figure eight

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Let $X=S^1 \times S^1$ and $A=S^1 \vee S^1$. The question asks to compute $H_n(X,A)$ with coefficients $R$.

By the short exact sequences, we have $0\to C_n(A)\to C_n(X)\to C_n(X,A) \to 0$. Since $C_0(A)=C_0(X)=R$,  $C_1(A)=C_1(X)=R^2$, and $C_2(X)=R$, can we conclude that $C_2(X,A)=R$ and $C_1(X,A)=C_0(X,A)=0$, and thus $H_2(X,A)=R$, $H_1(X,A)=H_0(X,A)=0$? I would really appreciate your help!

Comment: You can't conclude this without using properties of the specific embedding of the figure eight into the torus. It would be good to know what tools you have available: for example, are you using singular homology? Cellular? Simplicial? You say "the question," but from what book, what chapter, what section?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are using singular homology and the standard embedding of $A = S^1 \vee S^1$ into $X = S^1 \times S^1$.

Here are some hints:

- Convince yourself that $X/A \cong S^2$
- Use that $H_n(X,A) \cong H_n(X/A,*) \cong \tilde{H}_n(X/A)$ for all $n$

Can you finish the calculations by yourself now?